# Equivalent of the UIWebView selector webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: in MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

What is the equivalent of the *UIWebView* selector *webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:* in MonoTouch? From intellisense in MonoDevelop I see that the UIWebView has a property Delegate and also has a property *ShouldStartLoad* which is of type *UIWebLoaderControl*. Which of these is the correct way of setting up a delegate for the UIWebView such that the selector *webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:* can be defined and called when the UIWebView loads a request.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer to this question from an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399706/how-i-can-call-a-javascript-function-with-monotouch-and-vice-versa) posted by [miguel.de.icaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16929/miguel-de-icaza).

The way to solve this in MonoTouch is to hook up to the ShouldStartLoad property like this:

```
myView.ShouldStartLoad = (webView, request, navType) => {
     // Determine here what to do
}
```

Thanks, Miguel.

---

I am not sure why setting the *Delegate* property of the *UIWebView* to a *UIWebViewDelegate* object with a *ShouldStartLoad* overridden method did not work. Maybe someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: Also curious about this second part, set an instance of my custom webviewdelegate to the instance of my webview.delegate and none of the overridden members ever hit.