# Equivalent of Titanium Javascript fireEvent from Webview in Monotouch?

Tags: javascript, events, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, titanium

I am porting a titanium app to monotouch due to its high cost, but need to find a
way of sending a custom event from the UIWebView to the application.

Titanium has Ti.App.fireEvent, is there an equivalent?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question answers a similar problem:

[How I can call a javascript function with MonoTouch and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399706/how-i-can-call-a-javascript-function-with-monotouch-and-vice-versa)