# “SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF” when evaluating JavaScript in iOS UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, json, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I keep getting this error in JavaScript when trying to pass some JSON to a `UIWebView`:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

There is no line number or filename available in `window.onerror` but I've already checked all referenced files, and they are fine.

I'm using MonoTouch [`EvaluateJavaScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5407039/458193) method which is equivalent to ObjC [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:):

```
webView.EvaluateJavascript(
    "Viewer.init($('#page'), " + json.ToString() + ");"
);
```

It works just fine on “simple” JSON input but breaks at larger objects.
What could go wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Before passing an NSString to a UIWebView, be sure to escape newlines as well as single/double quotes:

```
NSString *html = @"<div id='my-div'>Hello there</div>";

html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\'" withString:@"\\\'"];
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];

NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"injectSomeHtml('%@');", html];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Comment: In my case (macOS 10.11+, Swift 4.x), replacing `\'` with `\\\'` is unnecessary.

Comment: for Swift 5.x, use html.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n")

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, I forgot to [escape newlines in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073/458193), and thus created an “unexpected EOF” for UIWebView.